# SwiftUI: @Published for trigger .sheet is crashing when try to save changed value

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, publisher

I wanna make some changes in `ViewModel` by passing items into the `.sheet` and decide to save it or leave without changes. But faced the problem when changing the item and dismissing `.sheet` with `@Environment(\.dismiss)` the app is crushing. I can't figure out why it gives this behavior. My goal is make changes into the item on a `.sheet` and control save it or not by pressing button. Would be thankful for help!

```
struct Transport: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

class TransportViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var transports = [Transport(name: "Airplane"), Transport(name: "Car"), Transport(name: "Ship")]
    @Published var editedTransport: Transport?
    
    func saveTransport() {
        if let unwrappedTransport = editedTransport {
            if let editedTransportIndex = transports.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == unwrappedTransport.id }) {
                transports[editedTransportIndex] = unwrappedTransport
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TransportListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var transportViewModel = TransportViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(transportViewModel.transports) { transport in
                Text(transport.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        transportViewModel.editedTransport = transport
                    }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $transportViewModel.editedTransport) {
            transportViewModel.editedTransport = nil
        } content: { _ in
            TransportEditSheet()
        }
        .environmentObject(transportViewModel)
    }
}

struct TransportEditSheet: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var transportViewModel: TransportViewModel
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Binding($transportViewModel.editedTransport).map { transport in
            List {
                TextField("", text: transport.name)
                Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                    Text("Cancel").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    transportViewModel.saveTransport()
                    dismiss() }) {
                    Text("Save").foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the first glance, the $ should be used with the published property, not the model. I wouldn’t assign nil, might create an infinite loop.

Comment: Probably better to have a @State property in the view for the selected transaction and use that instead in the `.sheet` call

Comment: That Binding in the body seems a bit of a stretch for SwiftUI s capabilities what is the point of using Binding there? There is no need for a 2 way connection

Comment: @loremipsum in this scenario Binding + Map is using for safe unwrap variable without losing functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this, seems to be working as expected

```
    struct Transport: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID().uuidString
        var name: String
    }

    class TransportViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var transports = [Transport(name: "Airplane"), Transport(name: "Car"), Transport(name: "Ship")]
        @Published var editedTransport: Transport?
        
        func saveTransport() {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if let unwrappedTransport = self.editedTransport {
                    if let editedTransportIndex = self.transports.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == unwrappedTransport.id }) {
                        self.transports[editedTransportIndex] = unwrappedTransport
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct TransportListView: View {
        
        @StateObject var transportViewModel = TransportViewModel()
        @State var editSheet = false
        
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(transportViewModel.transports) { transport in
                    Text(transport.name)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            transportViewModel.editedTransport = transport
                            editSheet = true
                        }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $editSheet) {
               TransportEditSheet()
            }
            .environmentObject(transportViewModel)
        }
    }

    struct TransportEditSheet: View {
        
        @EnvironmentObject var transportViewModel: TransportViewModel
        @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
        
        var body: some View {
            Binding($transportViewModel.editedTransport).map { transport in
                List {
                    TextField("", text: transport.name)
                    Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                        Text("Cancel").foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        transportViewModel.saveTransport()
                        dismiss() }) {
                        Text("Save").foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]